# Read XML response to JAVA and at the sametime capture XML as String to store in DB

Tags: xml, hibernate, jaxb, jersey, jax-rs

I'm new to Jersey framework JAX-RS. I have a requirement.

I read the XML response to Jaxb object.

```
        Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient();
        WebTarget webTarget = client.target("http://localhost:8080/rest/");         
        Response response = webTarget.path("provider").request(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML).get();
        ProviderBean providerBean = response.readEntity(ProviderBean.class); //My JAXB object. Will be used as a model for Hibernate
```

I'm using the same ProviderBean Jaxb object as a persistent model in Hibernate.

```
ProviderBean.java

@Entity
@Table(name="PROVIDER")
@XmlRootElement(name = "response")
public class ProviderBean{


}
```

Now, I can persist the Jaxb object using hibernate. But I need to have actual XML response sent by the client to store it in DB table.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<response>
  <provider>
    <provider_id>123</provider_id>
    <provider_name>abc</provider_name>
  </provider>
 </response>
```

I have to capture this XML response and store it in DB table say in a column called "RESPONSE_XML" in "TRANSACTION" table.

Solution I thought :
May be by marshalling the same Jaxb object to xml. The problem here is that since the same object is used for persistence I felt it could be complicated.

I know Response once read can't be read again. I tried searching all the methods under "Response" object. Is there any workaround ?

Any suggestions or help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Create a request/response filter (depends on the side where you want to store the XML) which lets you to access `InputStream`:

```
@PreMatching
@Priority(Integer.MIN_VALUE)
public class PersistenceFilter implements ContainerRequestFilter, ClientResponseFilter {

    @Override
    public void filter(final ClientRequestContext requestContext,
                       final ClientResponseContext responseContext)
        throws IOException {

        // client-side
        responseContext.setEntityStream(
            persistInboundEntity(responseContext.getEntityStream()));
    }

    @Override
    public void filter(final ContainerRequestContext requestContext)
        throws IOException {

        // server-side
        requestContext.setEntityStream(
            persistInboundEntity(requestContext.getEntityStream()));
    }

    private InputStream persistInboundEntity(InputStream stream)
        throws IOException {

        if (!stream.markSupported()) {
            stream = new BufferedInputStream(stream);
        }

        // Store InputStream / Create an byte array.

        // Reset it so Jersey can read it too.
        stream.reset();
        return stream;
    }
}
```

Don't forget to reset the stream at the end so Jersey can read it too.

Comment: Thank you very much for your information. Kept this logic away for a while and doing other stuffs. Going to try this one now.

Answer (score 0):

After trying several ways of doing, finally after refering the spec i found one simple solution that resolves what i was looking for. And here it is,

```
    Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient();
    WebTarget webTarget = client.target("http://localhost:8080/rest/");         
    Response response = webTarget.path("provider").request(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML).get();
    boolean bufferSts = response.bufferEntity(); // This is the solution im looking
    ProviderBean providerBean = response.readEntity(ProviderBean.class); //My JAXB object. Will be used as a model for Hibernate
    String xmlRes = response.readEntity(String.class); // I can read the response again
```

For more detail : https://java.net/projects/jax-rs-spec/sources/git/show/src/jax-rs-api/src/main/java/javax/ws/rs/core/Response.java - bufferEntity